# How to add buttons programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have created a button programmatically and i have passed it into a listbutton

I am trying to get the hover method to work on it but it does not work. when i make the button manually and pass it through the button list  it works.

Design

```
<Window x:Class="KinectButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000" Background="#FFAD4747" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="261*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="717*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Background="#FF371780" Name="canvas" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Controls:HoverButton Margin="0" Padding="0" x:Name="kinectButton" ImageSize="50"                                           
                                ImageSource="/Images/RightHand.png"  
                                ActiveImageSource="/Images/RightHand.png" 
                                TimeInterval="2000"  Panel.ZIndex="1000" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" />
            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button1" Height="152" Canvas.Left="128" Canvas.Top="162" Width="320" Background="#FF64C02F" FontSize="53.333" Click="button1_Click" BorderThickness="4" Foreground="White" />
            <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button2" Height="152" Canvas.Left="514" Canvas.Top="162" Width="320" Background="#FFFFF600" FontSize="53.333" Click="button2_Click" BorderThickness="4" Foreground="Black" />
            <Label Canvas.Left="322" Canvas.Top="34" Content="Kinect Buttons Demo" Height="58" Name="label1" FontSize="28" Width="302" Foreground="White" />
            <Label Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="524" Content="" Height="66" Name="message" Width="530" Foreground="White" FontSize="40" />
            <Button Canvas.Left="804" Canvas.Top="23" Content="Quit" Height="91" Name="quitButton" Width="137" FontSize="28" Background="#FFFF3838" Foreground="White" Click="quitButton_Click" />

            <Controls:HoverButton ActiveImageSource="/Images/RightHand.png" Canvas.Left="71" Canvas.Top="6" ImageSize="50" ImageSource="/Images/RightHand.png" Name="kinectButton2" Padding="0" Panel.ZIndex="1000" TimeInterval="2000" />
            <StackPanel Height="621" Name="stackPanel1" Width="935" Canvas.Left="71" Canvas.Top="70" />
        </Canvas>
        <Image Height="128" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="489,500,0,0" Name="videoStream" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace KinectButton
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
        private KinectSensor _Kinect;
        private WriteableBitmap _ColorImageBitmap;
        private Int32Rect _ColorImageBitmapRect;
        private int _ColorImageStride;
        private Skeleton[] FrameSkeletons;

        List<Button> buttons;
        static Button selected;

        float handX;
        float handY;

        float handX2;
        float handY2;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeButtons();
            kinectButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(kinectButton_Click);

            this.Loaded += (s, e) => { DiscoverKinectSensor(); };
            this.Unloaded += (s, e) => { this.Kinect = null; };
        }

        private void InitializeButtons()
        {
            newBtn.Content = "Hello";
            newBtn.Width = 500;
            newBtn.Height = 500;
            newBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(newBtn_Click);
            buttons = new List<Button> { button1, button2, quitButton,newBtn};
        }

        private void DiscoverKinectSensor()
        {
            KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += KinectSensors_StatusChanged;
            this.Kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);
        }

        private void KinectSensors_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Status)
            {
                case KinectStatus.Connected:
                    if (this.Kinect == null)
                    {
                        this.Kinect = e.Sensor;
                    }
                    break;
                case KinectStatus.Disconnected:
                    if (this.Kinect == e.Sensor)
                    {
                        this.Kinect = null;
                        this.Kinect = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == KinectStatus.Connected);
                        if (this.Kinect == null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Sensor Disconnected. Please reconnect to continue.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public KinectSensor Kinect
        {
            get { return this._Kinect; }
            set
            {
                if (this._Kinect != value)
                {
                    if (this._Kinect != null)
                    {
                        UninitializeKinectSensor(this._Kinect);
                        this._Kinect = null;
                    }
                    if (value != null && value.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
                    {
                        this._Kinect = value;
                        InitializeKinectSensor(this._Kinect);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void UninitializeKinectSensor(KinectSensor kinectSensor)
        {
            if (kinectSensor != null)
            {
                kinectSensor.Stop();
                kinectSensor.ColorFrameReady -= Kinect_ColorFrameReady;
                kinectSensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= Kinect_SkeletonFrameReady;
            }
        }

        private void InitializeKinectSensor(KinectSensor kinectSensor)
        {
            if (kinectSensor != null)
            {
                ColorImageStream colorStream = kinectSensor.ColorStream;
                colorStream.Enable();
                this._ColorImageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(colorStream.FrameWidth, colorStream.FrameHeight,
                    96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
                this._ColorImageBitmapRect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorStream.FrameWidth, colorStream.FrameHeight);
                this._ColorImageStride = colorStream.FrameWidth * colorStream.FrameBytesPerPixel;
                videoStream.Source = this._ColorImageBitmap;

                kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(new TransformSmoothParameters()
                {
                    Correction = 0.5f,
                    JitterRadius = 0.05f,
                    MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f,
                    Smoothing = 0.5f
                });

                kinectSensor.SkeletonFrameReady += Kinect_SkeletonFrameReady;
                kinectSensor.ColorFrameReady += Kinect_ColorFrameReady;
                kinectSensor.Start();
                this.FrameSkeletons = new Skeleton[this.Kinect.SkeletonStream.FrameSkeletonArrayLength];

            }
        }

        private void Kinect_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (ColorImageFrame frame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    byte[] pixelData = new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];
                    frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelData);
                    this._ColorImageBitmap.WritePixels(this._ColorImageBitmapRect, pixelData, this._ColorImageStride, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        private void Kinect_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.FrameSkeletons);
                    Skeleton skeleton = GetPrimarySkeleton(this.FrameSkeletons);

                    if (skeleton == null)
                    {
                        kinectButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Joint primaryHand = GetPrimaryHand(skeleton);
                        TrackHand(primaryHand);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //track and display hand
        private void TrackHand(Joint hand)
        {
            if (hand.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
            {
                kinectButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                kinectButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

                DepthImagePoint point = this.Kinect.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(hand.Position, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
                handX = (int)((point.X * LayoutRoot.ActualWidth / this.Kinect.DepthStream.FrameWidth) - (kinectButton.ActualWidth / 2.0));
                handY = (int)((point.Y * LayoutRoot.ActualHeight / this.Kinect.DepthStream.FrameHeight) - (kinectButton.ActualHeight / 2.0));

                handX2 = (int)((point.X * LayoutRoot.ActualWidth / this.Kinect.DepthStream.FrameWidth) - (kinectButton2.ActualWidth / 2.0));

                handY2 = (int)((point.Y * LayoutRoot.ActualHeight / this.Kinect.DepthStream.FrameHeight) - (kinectButton2.ActualHeight / 2.0));

                Canvas.SetLeft(kinectButton, handX);
                Canvas.SetTop(kinectButton, handY);

                Canvas.SetLeft(kinectButton2, handX2);
                Canvas.SetTop(kinectButton2, handY2);

                if (isHandOver(kinectButton, buttons)) kinectButton.Hovering();
                else kinectButton.Release();

                    kinectButton.ImageSource = "/Images/RightHand.png";
                    kinectButton.ActiveImageSource = "/Images/RightHand.png";

                    kinectButton.ImageSource = "/Images/LeftHand.png";
                    kinectButton.ActiveImageSource = "/Images/LeftHand.png";
            }
        }

        //detect if hand is overlapping over any button
        private bool isHandOver(FrameworkElement hand, List<Button> buttonslist)
        {
            var handTopLeft = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(hand), Canvas.GetTop(hand));
            var handX = handTopLeft.X + hand.ActualWidth / 2;
            var handY = handTopLeft.Y + hand.ActualHeight / 2;

            foreach (Button target in buttonslist)
            {
                Point targetTopLeft = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(target), Canvas.GetTop(target));
                if (handX > targetTopLeft.X &&
                    handX < targetTopLeft.X + target.Width &&
                    handY > targetTopLeft.Y &&
                    handY < targetTopLeft.Y + target.Height)
                {
                    selected = target;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        //get the hand closest to the Kinect sensor
        private static Joint GetPrimaryHand(Skeleton skeleton)
        {
            Joint primaryHand = new Joint();
            if (skeleton != null)
            {
                primaryHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
                Joint rightHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                if (rightHand.TrackingState != JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
                {
                    if (primaryHand.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
                    {
                        primaryHand = rightHand;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (primaryHand.Position.Z > rightHand.Position.Z)
                        {
                            primaryHand = rightHand;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return primaryHand;
        }

        //get the skeleton closest to the Kinect sensor
        private static Skeleton GetPrimarySkeleton(Skeleton[] skeletons)
        {
            Skeleton skeleton = null;
            if (skeletons != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < skeletons.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (skeletons[i].TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                    {
                        if (skeleton == null)
                        {
                            skeleton = skeletons[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (skeleton.Position.Z > skeletons[i].Position.Z)
                            {
                                skeleton = skeletons[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return skeleton;
        }

        void newButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yay");
        }

        void kinectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            selected.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent, selected));
        }

        private void newBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hey");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            message.Content = "Button 2 clicked!";
            Window w = new Window();
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Content = "Button A";

            canvas.Children.Add(newBtn);

            // stackPanel1.Children.Add(newBtn);

            stackPanel1.Children.Remove((UIElement)this.FindName("Button0"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer idealistic buttons.

Comment: Just take a step back and examine your options. Gather all of relevant information so you can make the best decision possible.

Comment: its easier to create them pragmatically when you need to loop through a good 20 buttons

Comment: Hello @user1262532.  Your question does not seem to ultimately relate to the Kinect, though your application may be based around it.  If this is true, please edit your question to only include the relevant code for the question.  The large amount of unrelated code makes it more difficult for others examine your question.

Comment: Deciding to dynamically create buttons might very well be pragmatic, @user1262532

Comment: Im not familiar with Kinect, but in XAML-based technologies, you're not supposed to go around messing with the Visual Tree. Create a proper ViewModel to represent your buttons (with an `ObservableCollection` or something) and then create an `ItemsControl`-based UI to show these items.

Answer (score 0):

The follow code would recreate your first button in code:

```
Button btn = new Button
{
    Name = "button1",
    Content = "Button1",
    Height = 152,
    Width = 320,
    Foreground = "#FF64C02F",
    FontSize = 53.333,
    BorderThickness = 4
};
btn.Click += button1_Click;

canvas.Children.Add(btn);
Canvas.SetLeft(btn, 128);
Canvas.SetTop(btn, 162);
```

That said... it is *not* preferable that you do this in code.  If you have 20 buttons (as you mention in your question comments) you should create them in XAML.

If you truly want to deal with them strictly in code, you should set up an [MVVM-style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) application.  These types of models can be very robust, but are complex to learn at first.